# Copy file to clipboard in Delphi

Tags: delphi, clipboard

Anybody know how to copy file in Delphi? It likes press Ctrl+ C on a file or folder, and then we can Paste at somewhere ? I just know how to copy a text by Clipbrd Unit, but i don't know with a file, folder !
Please help me !

Comment: You asked this once. Don't ask again in new question. Please fix the original question. Edit it and we can reopen it. Did you follow the advice I gave you there in comments. Did you try anything? Can you demonstrate any effort?

Comment: oh sorry ! It's first time i ask an question on this website. And there are some non-hope problems

Comment: No. This is your second question. This is a duplicate of [Copy file from Tlistview and paste by Teracopy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533232/copy-file-from-tlistview-and-paste-by-teracopy) The answer you accepted is nothing more than the comment placed at the other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clipboard and drag&drop have a lot in common. Most of libraries for support of drag&drop also have all what you need for clipboard. For example check this lib:
http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/

It is free, with full sourcecode and has a lot of examples, including for clipboard operations.

One of examples is DragDrop\Demos\Unicode\DragDropUnicode.dproj, it has popup command "Copy to clipboard":

```
procedure TForm1.ActionFileCopyExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (FFiles = '') then
    DropFileSource1.Files.Text := LoadResString(0)
  else
    DropFileSource1.Files.Text := FFiles;

  DropFileSource1.CopyToClipboard;
end;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried it, but it occured error when compiling for Delphi XE3. However, thank you !

Comment: @user: Ok, officially it doesn't support XE3, but actually it takes about 10 minutes to adopt it for XE3: open DragDropD2011.dpk and save it as DragDropXE3.dpk, use CF_LOCALE const instead of CF_MAX-1 (compiler shows where), replace definition of some methods (copy-paste from definition of corresponding interfaces, compiler shows what method of what interface), replace in 1-2 places integer to NativeInt or something like this (compiler shows where), ... And after that you will have powerfull and handy tool.

Comment: It occured this error afer fix CF_MAX-1 error :
[dcc32 Error] DragDropContext.pas(66): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IContextMenu3.HandleMenuMsg2

Comment: @user: If you read my previous comment a bit more carefully you will find what you should use instead of CF_MAX-1. And HandleMenuMsg2 (+with few other methods) is not missed, it just has a bit different parameters, so it is enough to copy method definition from corresponding interface. Plus as i remember one parameter was renamed (uType instead of uFlags or vise versa).

Comment: Answer to the question *How to copy file or folder to clipboard ?* shouldn't be *Go and get Drag and Drop Component Suite for Delphi. It has lot of examples.* That's merely a comment. [though I'm not voting down]

Comment: @TLama Why not ? If there is free library with full sourcecode to solve the problem, it is easiest and most usefull help - just share the link. I understand that it can be used for spam and ads, but it is not the case (i hope:). I don't thinks that answer "implement CF_HDROP yourself and read MSDN" is better in this case. And i don't think that it would be better if i suggest peace of sourcecode from this or another library.

Comment: In my view it's nothing more or less than a link only answer. Answer which doesn't essentially answer the question, but just points to a library. As I got it you've said, clipboard is almost the same as drag & drop. Most of libraries for drag & drop has what you need, so go and get this one. It is free with a lot of examples (from which if you search them through) find the one which can help you.

Comment: so, now i can't use this component, is Andrei Galatyn free to fix a XE3 ver of DragDrop component, i'm not so good at Delphi :D, please !

Comment: @user What do you mean "can't use". Did you compiled and installed it ? I added small piece of code from example (comes with library). It demonstrates how to place some files to the clipboard.

Comment: i can't install this component. the are some error and i just can solve some of that.
[dcc32 Error] DragDropContext.pas(66): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IContextMenu3.HandleMenuMsg2

Comment: the error is occur on this line : 'TDropContextMenu = class(TInterfacedComponent, IShellExtInit, IContextMenu,
    IContextMenu2, IContextMenu3)'
error : [dcc32 Error] DragDropContext.pas(66): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IContextMenu3.HandleMenuMsg2
Can you guide me how to resole this error

Comment: exactly say, i want to copy a lot of folder to clipboard :D, not file

Comment: The new Drag and Drop Component Suite for Delphi by landrix: https://github.com/landrix/The-new-Drag-and-Drop-Component-Suite-for-Delphi Tested on Delphi XE5

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`CF_HDROP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx#CF_HDROP) format to store the file/folder's full path, or use the [`CF_SHELLIDLIST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx#CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST) format to store the file/folder's `ITEMIDLIST`.  Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Shell Clipboard Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx)

Alternatively, convert the folder/file path(s) to `ITEMIDLIST` value(s) using [`SHParseDisplayName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236.aspx), [`ILCreateFromPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378420.aspx), or other similar function, then use [`SHCreateDataObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762126.aspx) to create an `IDataObject` from them, and then pass that to [`OleSetClipboard()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686623.aspx).